# Sharepoint Foundation 2013 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ID' of undefined

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I've deployed SharePoint Foundation 2013.

Some information about our SharePoint system:

I have 3 server for serving this Sharepoint

- ServerA: Sharepoint foundation 2013 version 15.0.4569.1506
- ServerB: SQL server 2012 developer
- ServerC: OWA

I'm facing the problem is while input data to task list the loading icon keep loading... 
When I press f5 or click other page the text "hi" will be lost (see the image below)

[image: Image 1]

I debug on browser it show me error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ID' of undefined
[image: Error]

How can I workaround this problem? Anyone can help?

Many thanks

Comment: Do u face this issue with other task list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add item in gantt view,

You need to show **Title, Start date, Due Date, Percent complete and predecessors** columns in gantt view & then need to specify values for them while adding new item. because these columns are required to get gantt chart works. So try to specifying values for all these columns.

**Specify columns & also add it to view :**

[image]

**Specify values for all these columns:**

[image]

Enter '0' in Percent complete. Predecessors column is optional.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you @Vishal. By the way, how can I mark your answer as best answer?

Comment: You already did it & glad it helped you.